# Existing ForkJoinPool or ExecutorService?

Tags: java, concurrency, executorservice, executors

I have a silly problem, I need an ExecutorService (and ForkJoinPool is such a thing) but I don't really want to initialise a new one and keep that reference, I remember a while back running into a JDK class that maintained an static ForkJoinPool for various uses and that could be used by other processes, but I can't seem to find it and there is not that much info about such a thing online. Does any know if such a thing exists ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ForkJoinPool.commonPool()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html#commonPool--) is a single, static instance

You can use [`Executors.newWorkStealingPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newWorkStealingPool--) to get a work stealing pool (which uses `ForkJoinPool.defaultForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory` under the hood), but that would require you to store the pool reference.

Both of these will therefore be per-JVM (per-process), not cross-process as you say you need, I don't know of a pool you can use to do that.

Comment: Yeah, ForkJoinPool.commonPool() was what I needed, thank you :) I didn't want to create a new ExecutorService instance of any type, storing the reference to it was not a problem for me, only the creation was.